# How to remove the first fragment added to the FragmentManager and start a fresh BackStack?

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment-backstack

So I decided to use the Fragment backstack in my Single Activity, Multiple Fragments pet project, and I'm running into problems right from the start.

My app flow is like this -> Activity starts, then does this:

```
supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
        .add(R.id.container, OnboardingFragment.newInstance())
        .commit()
```

This first fragment is OnboardingFragment, then the user navigates forward to SignInFragment, where I have this method in my Activity:

```
fun replaceFragment(fragment: Fragment) {
    supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
        .replace(R.id.container, fragment)
        .addToBackStack(null)
        .commit()
}
```

I use this method to start `SignInFragment()`, and I continue to use this method for the navigating the app afterwards.

However, what I'd like to do is after the user signs in, I'd like to completely remove all the backstack entries and Fragments, and start with a clean slate.

The problem with that is if do `popBackStack` until `backStackEntryCount == 0`, the `OnboardingFragment` is never popped off the stack, because it wasn't added to it in the first place. Adding it to backstack at the beginning introduced a bug where the backstack is cleaned, but you'd have an empty view if you press Back or Up.

I tried doing `remove(OnboardingFragment())`, but that didn't work either, and doing `add(R.id.container, Fragment())` on top of it doesn't work either because its UI remains underneath the new UI. even hide() didn't work. Why does that happen anyway?

TLDR; how can I remove the first fragment added to the container, if it's not on the back stack?

Comment: Maybe better approach would be to keep credentials `Fragments` for example `sign in` and `sign up` stick to one `Actvity`. Than after user successfully creates account or sign in rest `Fragments` stick to another `Activity`. On that way after sign in or sign up you could start fresh new `Activity` with clear `BackStack`

Comment: Yes I've thought about this as well, but I wanted to know if there was still a way to do it in a single `Activity` flow. I guess this is the only way?

Comment: You can `loop` through `BackStackEntryCount()` and each iteration call `popBackStack`.

Comment: That's what I'm doing, but the first `Fragment` isn't on the backstack so it can't be removed that way.

Answer (score 0):

> how can I remove the first fragment added to the container, if it's not on the back stack?

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();

//for adding the first fragment, save a reference to it
Fragment fragment = new Fragment();
fragmentManager.beginTransaction().add(R.id.fragment_container, fragment).commit();

//for removing the first fragment
fragmentManager.beginTransaction().remove(fragment).commit();
```

**Or** you can do it without saving a reference to your first fragment by following line of code:

```
fragmentManager.beginTransaction().remove(fragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_container)).commit();
```